# String or object compairson in Python 3.52

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality

I am working on the exorcism.io clock exercise and I can not figure out why this test is failing. The results look identical and even have the same type.

Here is my code:

```
class Clock:
    def __init__(self, h, m):
        self.h = h
        self.m = m
        self.adl = 0

    def make_time(self):
        s = self.h * 3600
        s += self.m * 60
        if self.adl: s += self.adl

        while s > 86400:
            s -= 86400

        if s == 0:
            return '00:00'

        h = s // 3600

        if h:
            s -= h * 3600

        m = s // 60
        return '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(h, m)

    def add(self, more):
        self.adl = more * 60
        return self.make_time()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.make_time()) # i don't think I need to do this

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl1 = Clock(34, 37) #10:37
    cl2 = Clock(10, 37) #10:37
    print(type(cl2))
    print(cl2, cl1)
    print(cl2 == cl1) #false
```

Comment: You haven't defined an equality comparison for these objects, so they inherit the default identity-based `==` from `object`.

Comment: @user2357112 That was it. Thanks! Also needed to put the new hour and minute in the self dictionary.

Comment: Please don't add a solution to your question. You are welcome to add your own answer below instead. Remember that Stack Overflow posts are meant to be helpful to future visitors with the same problem, and that answers are voted on independently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom class without an [`__eq__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) defaults to testing for *identity*. That is to say, two references to an instance of such a class are only equal if the reference they exact same object.

You'll need to define a custom `__eq__` method that returns `True` when two instances contain the same time:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Clock):
        return NotImplemented
    return (self.h, self.m, self.adl) == (other.h, other.m, other.adl)
```

By returning the `NotImplemented` singleton for something that is not a `Clock` instance (or a subclass), you let Python know that the `other` object could also be asked to test for equality.

However, your code accepts values greater than the normal hour and minute ranges; rather than store hours and minutes, store seconds and normalise that value:

```
class Clock:
    def __init__(self, h, m):
        # store seconds, but only within the range of a day
        self.seconds = (h * 3600 + m * 60) % 86400
        self.adl = 0

    def make_time(self):
        s = self.esconds
        if self.adl: s += self.adl
        s %= 86400
        if s == 0:
            return '00:00'

        s, h = s % 3600, s // 3600
        m = s // 60
        return '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(h, m)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Clock):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.seconds, self.adl) == (other.seconds, other.adl)
```

Now your two clock instances will test equal because internally they store the exact same time in a day. Note that I used the `%` modulus operator rather than a `while` loop and subtracting.

Comment: I added a eq function just like the your suggestion. The test in __main__ now works but the unit test still fails. AssertionError: <clock.Clock object at 0x7ff8ea8cb588> != <clock.Clock object at 0x7ff8ea8cb5c0>.

Comment: @Eman: right, because it only tests if `h` and `m` are exactly equal. You'd have to normalise those values when you create the `Clock` instance.

Comment: @Eman: I've added a suggestion to that effect, normalising the `h` and `m` inputs to a `seconds` value.

Comment: thanks, that was it. I was not considering the h and m vars have not been processed by make_time when _eq_ is called. What is the best way to show the final code, append to the question or answer my own?

Comment: @Eman: you don't need to show the final code; future visitors will always have to adapt the answer to their own situation anyway.